# How to dynamically add data from a span tag into a href tag

Tags: javascript, html

I think this may have a simple answer that I'm missing. The following tag inserts a TV show name into any page on my website:

```
<span class="show-title"></span>
```

what I'm trying to do is incorporate that data dynamically into a HREF URL link.

So,  let's say on the page I'm on:  
produced the result:  GOTHAM.

I'd like to then use that data to create this  url:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GOTHAM_(TV_series)

So I'm trying stuff like:

```
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/<span class="show-title"></span>_(TV_series)"> Link</a>
```

or

```
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" <span class='show-title'></span> _(TV_series)"> Link </a>
```

nothing working - any help would be awesome.  Thanks!

Comment: are the result store in javascript?

Comment: You can't have a span within an href attribute. You'll have to handle it separately in javascript.

Comment: I've removed the `json` and `jquery` tags as it seems your question is not related to either.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

In HTML

```
<a class="wikipedia-link">Link</a>
```

And your JavaScript function:

```
setLink(showTitle) {
  var link = document.getElementsByClassName("wikipedia-link");
  link.setAttribute("href", "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + showTitle + "_(TV_series)");
}
```

Comment: It would be best to use `encodeURIComponent(showTitle)`, instead of just adding `showTitle` directly.

Comment: this is leaving the link blank for me.

Answer (score 0):

The html you use is wrong. `span` shouldn't be inside tag `a`. No tag inside another.

If your result is in javascript variable, you can set the url using jquery.

```
$('a').attr('href', "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + result + "_(TV_series)");
```

`result` variable is your desired result.

Comment: It would be best to use `encodeURIComponent(result)`, instead of just adding `result` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Although there's better ways of going about doing this, I'm going to answer the question in the context in which you presented it:

First, give the url link a class or ID so you can easily select it with JavaScript to change the `href` value later. Also, don't try to nest the `span` tag anywhere inside the `a` tag. Leave it outside.

```
<span class="show-title">GOTHAM</span>
<a href="#" class="show-wikipedia-link">Link</a>
```

Next, in a JavaScript file or a `<script>` tag, define your variables:

`var showTitle, showWikipediaLink, linkElement`

Then, assign value to your newly defined variables

```
linkElement = document.querySelector('.show-wikipedia-link');
showTitle = document.querySelector('.show-title').innerText;
showWikipediaLink = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + showTitle + '_(TV_series)';
```

Finally, use JavaScript to update the `href` value of the link element to the show's Wikipedia link:

```
linkElement.href = showWikipediaLink;
```